# Can I import data from web store directly to Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that analyzes data uploaded into a sheet from a `.csv` file that is downloaded from my store for various operations and reports that I extract from it.  I would like to know if there is a method to make calls directly to my store database to retrieve the report automatically so the sheet always has up to date info.

Answer (score 0):

Try [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en)

> Imports data at a given url in .csv (comma-separated value) or .tsv (tab-separated value) format.
>
> **Sample Usage**
>
> `IMPORTDATA("http://www.census.gov/2010census/csv/pop_change.csv")`
>
> `IMPORTDATA(A2)`

Comment: A very useful tool indeed!  Unfortunately, I am learning that IMPORTDATA requires a publicly accessible webpage and my data is sensitive.  I am turning to look into an API call to the database instead using my API key and store url.  I found a 3dCart API Loader that allows me make queries.  Now I need to develop the proper query to return the data set I need (Top Products, Last 30 Days, With Item Options Considered) and it will be complete.  Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to add all the relevant details of what you are looking for.